# Network folder setup problem

Tags: networking, nautilus, 17.10, scanner, shared-folders

i feel like i'm struggling massively with something that should be simple.

I need to give my scanner (hp color laserjet pro m477fdw, all-in-one machine) access to a shared folder on my ubuntu machine.

The settings are on the printer itself and the menu is accessed by entering it's ip-adress in my browser like one would access a router/modem.

All the printer needs to know is the correct (complete) pathway and username and password so it can save the documents over the network on my pc.

To make it simple i shared the folder, although i'm not entirely certain that that is neccessairy.

The scanner does test and save the settings if done correctly, but sofar i haven't been able to.

So for this there is no need for xsane or simple scan via the pc itself. as all the command are given directly from the scanner itself.

When this works i would like to create a similar access to a shared folder on my linux based asustor-nas but for now my Ubuntu machine has priority!

local ip of the laptop is: 192.168.0.204
local ip of the scanner/printer is :192.168.0.101
location of the shared folder is: Scanned in the folder Documents

the setup in done directly in the scanner itself (not via hplip) so by accessing it through it's local ip (192.168.0.101)

after entering the parameters it checks the connection via test and save. which only gives the reply:

The test was unsuccessful. Try again.

so not very informative.

als i'm not entirely sure which slash to use \ or /, always thought \ was for winsdows and / for linux. but since smb is windows related i'm getting confused, but it is essential.

oh and I let nautilus use the standard settings for the shared folder.

i must add now that i reinstalled ubuntu 17.10 from scratch! 
placed a folder with the same name in Documents and created a share. 
but wile setting this up i got a error msg.

could not find libpam-smbpass.!

i can't recall getting that notification when i did it the first time, but am not entirely sure about this.

so i tried to install this from synaptic, but ran into the wayland session bug for synaptic. so logged off and ran x11.

tried to install.. but was nothing to actually install.

then i ran

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo apt-get remove --purge smbclient libsmbclient
sudo apt-get install smbclient libsmbclient
```

and got no warnings / errors.

oh i also tried to find the full path name in the terminal by:

```
# pwd
/home/matt/Documents/Scanned
```

(copy pasted so no type-0)

last few attempts i focessed in these 3 links:
- //192.168.0.204/home/matt/Documents/Scanned
- //192.168.0.204/home/Documents/Scanned
- //192.168.0.204/home/Scanned

i assume it's using smb protocol, but am not sure of this.. 
(i read somewhere that it does on windows machines)

anyway i have tried all possible instances of the path with slashed to each side but i can't seem to get it to actually pass the test and save.

personally i believe the first two steps to solve is to check is there is still an issue with libpam-smbpass or not and also become sure which direction the / or \ should face.

thanks for any help, and please ask for as much info as needed

Matt :)

added:

```
# touch /home/matt/Documents/Scanned/testing123
```

it created an empty document named testing123 in the folder.

Comment: What's your goal? To scan documents and save them in this shared folder?

Comment: exactly that, All info i apparently need is the correct path of the folder over the network and my login data, there is nothing more to enter.  or maybe i did something wrong with the setting up the shared folder, but nautilus did it basically for me .

Comment: I don't know if it is a type but normally it is **h**ome, lowercase. Also, can you please edit your question and tell us a little bit more about your setup ? i.e. what type of scanner you are using, where/how you are doing the setup on the scanner, if you get any error messages, etc

Comment: Do YOU have access to the folder you are attempting to save scans to? what's the output of `touch /home/matt/Documents/Scanned/testing123` Please [edit] your post with your responses to requested information. Thank you for helping us help you! Also you appear to be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-share/+bug/1726143)

Comment: as excpected, file created, no error msg. but that is done on the same machine as the folder is located on. none the less, tested and tried. and yeah. i believe so (about the bug)

Comment: At the risk of repeating @RobertRiedl , what make and model of scanner are you using? Also can you scan and save successfully into any other folder? Are you using `simple-scan`, `xsane` or something else entirely? Please [edit] this information into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ elder Geek, thank you for reminding me. i actually added that info already in the text but some how i edited out again , unintentionally. i will modify it again, answering also your questions. my apologie.

Comment: According to the HP setup video, the network shares are added as `\\ServerIP\sharedfolder`  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnKjedhrbOs  Around 1:50 it shows that info.

Answer (score 2):

** Don't be obsessed with libpam-smbpass or any of the other pam's they are a non issue.

** You say you created the share of Scanned through nautilus. You can verify if that was successful by looking at the output of this command:

```
net usershare info --long
```

** All of these are incorrect:

> last few attempts i focessed in these 3 links:
>   - //192.168.0.101/home/matt/Documents/Scanned
>   - //192.168.0.101/home/Documents/Scanned
>   - //192.168.0.101/home/Scanned

It's form is //server/share so in this case it's:

```
//192.168.0.101/Scanned
```

Or `\\192.168.0.101\Scanned`

The internal path on the server that gets you to Scanned is defined in the share definition which you will see when you run the usershare command above .

You can try this yourself on your own machine. Open a terminal and run:

```
nautilus smb://192.168.0.101/Scanned
```

Do you see the testing123 file you added with touch?

**EDIT**: If you share requires credentials remember to add yourself to the samba password database:

> sudo smbpasswd -a matt

Comment: i'll try to answer all of these questions. i ran # net usershare info --long. the replay was the following comment.

Comment: [Scanned]
path=/home/matt/Documents/Scanned
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:R,Unix User\matt:F,
guest_ok=n

Comment: i made an error in my paths.. besides the one you mentioned. 192.168.0.101, is the ip of the printer/scanner itself. so i should use 192.168.0.204  (my pc's  ip) so i tried it in the form: //192.168.0.204/Scanned. but it didn't work.. :(

Comment: when i ran nautilus smb://192.168.0.204/Scanned, i got the following error msg: This location could not be displayed: sorry, could not display all the content of "192.168.0.204:smb": the specified location is not supported.

Comment: when i ran # touch /home/matt/Documents/Scanned/testing123, the (empty) file testing123 was added to Scanned folder.

Comment: maybe there is an issue with the user name / password? password is the one i use in to login to ubuntu / and sudo i prosume? and the username is what is returned when i type "whoami" exactly, no issues with capital / smaller letters foir the username?

Comment: Your share does not allow guest access so your device will need to pass credentials. Is that what you desire? Or do you want it to allow guest access and writeable to everyone? If you want the latter then go back into nautilus and change how you are sharing it by selecting all the boxes.

Comment: If you want the scanner to pass credentials and you want the user name to be matt then you need to add matt to the samba password database with this command - without quotes : "sudo smbpasswd -a matt".

Comment: The "specified location is not supported" error sounds like a missing package to me. Try installing gvfs-backends. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: And try //192.168.0.204/Scanned with the slashes reversed once you determine if you want to pass credentials or not.

Comment: Yes ! thank you :) it work.. pass the credentials from the scanner it is only for me to use so.  this seems like a nice and save option. and didn't need to try the reversed slashes, the path is at it is.

Comment: now please tell me what to do to make sure this bounty gets awarded to you?

Comment: PS: got it to work, so i can scan to my nas to now. SO many thanks :)

Comment: Never awarded a bounty before but the Help section states this: "Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answer" Maybe that is something only you can see?

Comment: i just did.. hope i did it right, you deserve it!

Answer (score 1):

The package [libpam-smbpass](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libpam-smbpass) was removed [upstream quite some time ago](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-cvs/2015-October/111473.html) for what appears to be security reasons.

```
pam_smbpass: REMOVE this PAM module

    This pam module causes GPLv3, thread-unsafe Samba code to be directly loaded
    into the address space of many system services.  The code in question was not
    expected to run in this context, and while using the Samba, rather than the system
    password file is a admirable goal, this needs to be done over inter-process
    communication, such as is done by pam_winbind.

    pam_winbind is not a total replacement, as the migrate functionality used
    to keep the Samba password up to date with the system password is not
    present, but otherwise can provide essentially the same services.

    Andrew Bartlett
```

A [confirmed bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-share/+bug/1726143) has been filed regarding this issue which you may wish to subscribe to.

It appears that utilizing `pam_winbind` instead is the secure workaround. For more on that see [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/pam_winbind.8.html) and [here.](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/pam.html)

**Edit:**

```
 When a PAM aware privilege granting application is started, it
       activates its attachment to the PAM-API. This activation performs a
       number of tasks, the most important being the reading of the
       configuration file(s): /etc/pam.conf. Alternatively, this may be the
       contents of the /etc/pam.d/ directory. The presence of this directory
       will cause Linux-PAM to ignore /etc/pam.conf.

me@zippy-64bit:~$ cat /etc/pam.conf
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# /etc/pam.conf                                  #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# NOTE
# ----
#
# NOTE: Most program use a file under the /etc/pam.d/ directory to setup their
# PAM service modules. This file is used only if that directory does not exist.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Format:
# serv. module     ctrl       module [path] ...[args..]          #
# name  type       flag
```

It looks to me like in Ubuntu the authorization settings are set in `/etc/pam.d/common-account` As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default. for more information on `pam-auth-update` see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/pam.conf.5.html)

Sources:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libpam-smbpass

https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-cvs/2015-October/111473.html

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/pam_winbind.8.html

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/pam.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/pam.conf.5.html

Comment: sorry.. that is a bit out of my league, so will have to ask a lot of questions. about the first "here" link.

Comment: i am told to modify the files services in /etc/pam.d/ but there is no file "services" should i create it? als tried to see if it was hidden. it wasn't  ps: help much appreciated!

Comment: @MatthieuKintsvan edited answer.

Comment: Hello Elder Geek, thank you for your effort. just to see if i understand correctly: the package libpam-smbpass has been removed because of security issues. it has been replaced by pam_winbind which has similar services. and to do this i need to edit the file: /etc/pam.d/common-account, instead of config /etc/pam.d/service. I should edit it as the first "here" link's head synopsis mentions?

Comment: i subscribed to the bug report.

Comment: apparently this wasn't the issue. none the less was your help much appreciated!